# Why mysql (mariadb) keeps asking for password even if the --password is in the command line?

Tags: mysql

This thing is driving me crazy. If I write:

```
mysql -unextcloud -pnextcloudpassword -h 127.0.0.1 -p 43306 -D nextcloud-db
```

I always and anyway get a `Enter password:` following (that can't even be aborted by Ctrl-C).

**Why? How can I avoid it?**

I've already tried every combination of `[-u|--user|-p|--password]` with any combination of space and =. And then I get a connection refused that makes absolutely no sense, but that's another problem (and another source of insanity).

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you use `-p` **twice** in that call? What have you tried to resolve this? And how is this related to programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you have a parm "...**-p 43306**..." - that's really the password 
 you probably want "...**--port=43306**...". .

 or use capital P for the port parm "...**-P43306**..."

If that doesn't help - can you post the actual response?
Cheers!

Comment: It was that. Dumb me! :(

Comment: Ha! I'm glad to be the extra set of eyes!

Comment: I was so mad about the connection refused error in spite of the `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` that I completely neglected the other params!